# How to enforce .Net Core project always take the file Build Action according to the file extension

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, csproj, roslyn-project-system

**The issue:**
If I change the file extension from the visual studio, the file `Build Action` will be according to the previous `Build Action` and not according to the new file extension.

There is a way to enforce the visual studio always takes the Build Action from the file extension?

**Example:**

1. Create a new .Net Core 3.1 Class library. There is a single file (`Class1.cs`) The `csproj` will be like this:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>

   </Project>
   ```
2. Change the name of `Class1.cs` to `Class1.txt` from the visual studio. The result, `Class1.txt` is with `Build Action` `Compile` although it is a text file. The content of csproj:

> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>
>       <PropertyGroup>
>         <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
>       </PropertyGroup>
>
>       <ItemGroup>
>         <None Remove="Class1.txt" />
>       </ItemGroup>
>
>       <ItemGroup>
>         <Compile Include="Class1.txt" />
>       </ItemGroup>
>
>     </Project>
> ```

**Additional information:**

1. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
2. If I change the file extension from the file system the issue doesn't appear.

**Update:**

A possible solution is to change the file `Build Action` after each file rename, but I want an automatic way.

Comment: I could see only one option as of now 
1. Right Click on File --> Properties
2. Build Action --> Set None and save your changes

Comment: @Prakash , I edited the post. A possible solution is to change the file `Build Action` after each file rename, but I want an automatic way.

Comment: I don't think there is  automatic way to do this, even VS 2017 behave in the same way.
but for newly added text file build action is always none.